# libmicrohttpd sending junk in html response (const char* vs std::string.data() )

Tags: c++

When I send my html using **std::string's data()** some garbage is sent instead in the beginning of the string:

**Working ok:**

```
    const char* html2 = "Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license";
    response = MHD_create_response_from_buffer(strlen(html2), (void *) html2, MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);
```

[image]

**Junk is sent:**

```
    std::string html = "Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license";
     response = MHD_create_response_from_buffer(strlen(html.data()), (void *) html.data(), MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);
```

[image]

Comment: See if using `c_str()` instead of `data()` fixes this

Comment: You don't need `strlen`, a string knows how long it is. Since we can't see your whole program we don't know if the string stays in scope the entire time or if the function you're using to create the response copies the data or not. You might consider using the MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY flag and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Which C++ standard are you using?

Comment: g++ -std=c++1z        - gcc.EXE (tdm64-1) 5.1.0

Comment: Yes, MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY fixes it, thanks heaps! Can you make it an answer so I accept please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/manual/html_node/microhttpd_002dresponse-create.html):

> mode
>
> memory management options for buffer; use MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT if
>   the buffer is static/global memory, use MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_FREE if the
>   buffer is heap-allocated and should be freed by MHD and
>   MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY if the buffer is in transient memory (i.e. on
>   the stack) and must be copied by MHD

It is evident that you must use `MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY` rather than `MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT`. Otherwise, as it seems, it will hold the pointer to `string::data()` past the life of the string, which is undefined behavior. The heap is simply being reused, and that's why you get junk.

Note that with the `char*` literal  "*the buffer is static/global memory*", so `MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT` works well with your first variant. But in the second variant is by no means adheres to "*the buffer is static/global memory*". The second variant is more in line with *"the buffer is in transient memory (i.e. on the stack)"*, so `MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY` must be the right choice.